# how to remove "Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event." warning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-iteration, lightning-record-form

I am using lightning record form inside aura iteration like this which is visible on hover

```
<aura:Iteration items="{!v.Accountscurrent}" var="acc" indexVar="index">
<span class=" icon slds-form-element__label" data-index="{!index}" onmouseenter="{!c.openPop}" onmouseleave="{!c.closePop}"><b>
   <a onclick="{!c.onclick}" data-index="{!index}"  target="_blank">{! acc.Name }</a>
<section aura:id="pop" aria-describedby="dialog-body-id-99" aria-labelledby="dialog-heading-id-104" class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left slds-hide popoveralign" role="dialog">
<div class="slds-popover__body popoverbodyalign" id="dialog-body-id-99">
 <lightning:recordForm aura:id="fullCmp"
             recordId="{!acc.Id}"
             objectApiName="Account"
              layoutType="Compact"
              mode="readonly" />
              </div>
              </section>
.......
```

for each aura iteration i am getting warning in console

**Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking event**. **Consider marking event handler as**  **passive to make the page more responsiv**

does anyone have any idea how can i remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that this is a [feature in DOM spec](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) which is handled by the Aura framework, there is nothing you can do about it and I highly doubt that anything will change in the aura framework, considering it has been archived.

So, you can't remove it. Try using LWC instead of Aura. (anyways, you should be using LWC moving forward.)